# Why do edo (eat) and edo (generate) have different forms?

Tags: verbs

Why do edo (eat) and edo (generate) have different forms?

So, for example, both are *edit* in the 3rd person singular. But in the 2nd person perfect, one is *edisti* and the other is *edidisti*.

They are both 3rd conjugation, so I guess they are supposed to be following the same paradigm, but there are differences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Knowing the four conjugations is useful, but is not sufficient to figure out the full paradigm of a verb. For example, some third-conjugation verbs form their perfects with *-s-* (*dixī*), others with reduplication (*cucurrī*), others with vowel changes (*ēgī*), and so on. Historically, these go back to a few different constructions in Proto-Indo-European that fell together in Proto-Italo-Celtic (or Proto-Italic and Proto-Celtic if you prefer). So there's no reliable way to predict which one a given verb will use.

So the standard way to learn a Latin verb is to memorize four principal parts:

- The first singular present active indicative, which is the citation form used to talk about the verb
- The present active infinitive, which tells you the conjugation, and thus tells you how to conjugate the present system; cut off the ending to get the "present stem"
- The first singular perfect active indicative, which tells you how to conjugate the perfect system; cut off the ending to get the "perfect stem"
- The supine or perfect passive participle, which is *usually* predictable from the perfect stem but not always

The two verbs you're talking about are

- *edō*, *edere* (or *ēsse*), ***ēdī***, *ēsus*
- *ēdō*, *ēdere*, ***ēdidī***, *ēditus*

And as you've seen, you need to know the third principal part to conjugate them in the perfect system; there's no reliable way to predict it from the other parts.

---

As for why they're like this, historically…

*Edō* is pretty regular, except for a couple weird present forms (which come from it being an athematic verb in Proto-Indo-European). It forms its perfect stem the same way as *agō*~*ēgī*, which is not unusual for the third conjugation.

*Ēdō* comes from *ē-* "out" plus *dō, dare, dedī, datus* "give". In the history of Latin, short vowels in medial syllables (i.e. not the first or last syllable of a word) got reduced, so **ēdare* regularly became *ēdere*, and **ēdatus* became *ēditus*. Synchronically, though, *ēdō* forms its perfect stem through reduplication, which is *also* not unusual for the third conjugation (compare *currō*~*cucurrī*).

Comment: Is  ēdō from dare "give" (from PIE *deh₃-) or it is from *dʰeh₁-? I find the etymology of Latin -dō, -dere, -didī, -ditum verbs confusing. The reduplication of a non-initial syllable is somewhat unusual (verbs that reduplicate often lack reduplication when prefixed)

Comment: @Asteroides I thought it was *deh₃ but google is suggesting that, in fact, most prefixed verbs I thought were from *deh₃ are actually from *dheh₁. Fascinating. I'll have to ask a new question about that.