# Which verbs come from *deh₃ and which from *dʰeh₁?

Tags: etymology, prefix, proto-indo-european

Latin has quite a few prefixed verbs looking like *-dō*, *-dere*, *-didī*, *-ditus* (*condō*, *abdō*, *reddō*, *trādō*, *ēdō*, etc).

I'd previously thought these came from the verb *dō*, *dare*, *dedī*, *datus* (< **deh₃* "give", Greek δίδωμι), with regular vowel reduction. But [as Asteroides pointed out to me](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16858/why-do-edo-eat-and-edo-generate-have-different-forms/16859#comment35148_16859), the etymology of these is unclear—they might instead come from **dʰeh₁* "put" (Greek τίθημι).

As Asteroides succinctly put it, "I find the etymology of Latin -dō, -dere, -didī, -ditum verbs confusing." Google confirmed that some of these verbs are thought to come from **dʰeh₁*, but I'm not totally clear on how, or which ones, or if the two merged somewhere in the history of Latin, or what. (And I don't have access to de Vaan or another reputable etymological dictionary at the moment.)

Can anyone offer clarity on this?

Comment: [They did partially merge, yeah.](https://i.imgur.com/llP34HF.png) Latin doesn't have a simplex equivalent to τίθημι (which would start with *f-* anyway), but in compounds it's often not possible to tell whether it's *\*deh₃-* or *\*dʰeh₁-*. Don't have it in me to write a full answer (I'd check what Weiss has to say as well), but it wouldn't be much more than this anyway.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Thanks for the reference! That's from de Vaan, I'm assuming? I'll see if I can find Weiss and write up a proper answer next week.

Comment: Yes, that's De Vaan.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Isn't *facio* the simplex equivalent to τίθημι?

Comment: @TKR Arguably, though it's badly mangled. I think it's pretty universally accepted that it contains *\*dʰh₁* and only marginally less universally that the *-k-* is from an old aorist or perfect, but I'm inclined to see the form as a deverbal (hence, then, the *-i-* < *\*-ye-*, though that also just forms presents) of whatever the cognate of θῆκα (the Homeric aorist, not the noun) was at the time rather than a remodeling of that simplex itself, and that the simplex itself was subsequently lost. De Vaan doesn't discuss that possibility, though.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly -- is what you're describing different from the usual theory that the *-k-* is from an old aorist cognate with ἔθηκα?

Comment: @TKR I agree that's where the *-k-* ultimately comes from, I just think it's likely *facio* is a deverbal derived from that aorist of the simplex, not a remodelling of the simplex itself by generalising the aorist's *-k-* to the other tenses for whatever reason.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Are there parallels for such a verb-to-verb derivation? It seems odd. And wouldn't you end up with *fēciō*? Analogical remodeling along the lines of *cēpī : capiō :: fēcī :: X* seems like an obvious source (and the reason would be that Italic was eliminating athematic verbs generally, and *fem* or whatever the reflex would be looked too weird).

Comment: de Vaan is available here: https://fr.1lib.pl/book/1253470/cbca84

Comment: @Cairnarvon See the Praeneste fibula, *med fhefhaked Numasioi* (which is a perfect, I know).